# Chef: mysql cookbook does not know root's password after I change it using mysqladmin

Tags: mysql, ruby, attributes, chef-infra, cookbook

I'm new to Chef (configuration management). I use mysql cookbook with all default attributes.
Running it makes it generate a random password for root account.
I can use the password with node['mysql']['server_root_password']. Then, I change mysql password using mysqladmin.
The variable node['mysql']['server_root_password'] is not updated to my new password.
How can I tell the mysql cookbook to update the value inside node['mysql']['server_root_password'] please?

Comment: Are you running Chef client (with server) or chef solo? What exactly do you want to update? The the value in attributes/server.rb?

Comment: I use Chef-server/Chef-client. In my recipe, I use the variable node['mysql']['server_root_password'] to login/run mysql script. But this variables holds the old password which is no longer valid since I have change my root password to a different value using mysqladmin. So the resource failes to execute.

Comment: In this case, just update it by hand in the recipe, because you manually changed the root password later for mysql -_- Or, probably you can override the node['mysql']['server_root_password'] by using a JSOn attribute file when executing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the node's attribute to reflect the new password.

One way to do that would be to use Knife and the [knife-set-attribute](https://github.com/amian84/knife-set-attribute) plugin.

```
knife set_attribute node mysql.server_root_password yournewpassword
```

Other ways to set attributes can be explored in the Chef [attribute docs](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_node_object.html).